# Use MathJax in ngFor Angular (2/4/5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mathjax

So, I've been trying to render mathematical equations on Angular 4 application using MathJax. Everything is working fine till I had to render single equation. But now I need to render the around 4 equations which is coming from an API.

Now, using the MathJax inside ngFor works only for the first object in the array but not after that. See screenshot below:

[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        //question HTML
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let answer of model.question?.options">
        <span class="answers" #answers>{{answer?.text}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, the component looks like this:

```
@ViewChild('equation') equation: ElementRef;

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.equation.nativeElement]);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.answers.nativeElement]);
```

Comment: Blind guess, doesn't it have something to do with `#answers` ? Isn't that supposed to be a unique ID and not repeated inside `*ngFor` ?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be unique. But, If I assign index to #answers, then I'm struggling with MathJax.Hub.Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        //question HTML
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let answer of model.question?.options">
        <span class="answers">{{answer?.text}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@ViewChild('equation') equation: ElementRef;

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.equation.nativeElement]);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.getElementsByClassName("answers")]);
```

'#  sintaxis is unique.

Comment: Okay. This works! Great. Thanks! I appreciate your approach.

Comment: You'r wellcome!

Comment: @AkashAgrawal Yes, that's exactly what I said in my comment above :)

Comment: I used your solution in my "report-detail.component.ts" & I got "Cannot find name 'MathJax'." error. Any ideas?

Comment: you maybe not imported properly MathJax library